# Find and Replace don't work in any JetBrains tools

Tags: jetbrains-ide

Find and replace features don't work in some of JetBrains tools. If I press <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>, special bar for searching/replacing opens, but cursor doesn't appear in a search field (cursor doesn't focus on the search field, instead remains in a code editing field). If I try to press on search field, nothing happens, cursor remains in the code field.

---

Problem occurs in the following tools:

- CLion 2018.1.2
- IDEA Ultimate 2018.1.3
- PhpStorm 2018.1.2
- PyCharm Professional 2018.1.2

---

All tools were installed via JetBrains Toolbox.

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: I wonder the same thing. I use that feature every day in CLion and PhpStorm (both 2017 versions). So either it's something that broke in the latest release or you have a platform issue. The version you cite is new but not new-today. I checked the JB issue-tracker and see no evidence it is a defect. There would be shouting if it was, I think.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It must be your environment. Use this link to create support ticket where you can provide your idea.log file and other info that might be needed. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731